# I am using pdfbox-app-2.0.0-RC3 but still I am getting Error while using RndomAccessFile in PDF parser

Tags: java, pdfbox

-You can see the example via this link:
http://radixcode.com/pdfbox-example-code-how-to-extract-text-from-pdf-file-with-java/

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class JavaPDFTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

       PDFManager pdfManager = new PDFManager();
       pdfManger.setFilePath("E:\test.pdf");
       System.out.println(pdfManager.ToText());       
    }    
}
```

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessFile;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

public class PDFManager {

   private PDFParser parser;
   private PDFTextStripper pdfStripper;
   private PDDocument pdDoc ;
   private COSDocument cosDoc ;

   private String Text ;
   private String filePath;
   private File file;

    public PDFManager() {

    }
   public String ToText() throws IOException
   {
       this.pdfStripper = null;
       this.pdDoc = null;
       this.cosDoc = null;

       file = new File(filePath);
       parser = new PDFParser(new RandomAccessFile(file,"r")); // update for PDFBox V 2.0

       parser.parse();
       cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
       pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
       pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
       pdDoc.getNumberOfPages();
       pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
       pdfStripper.setEndPage(10);

       // reading text from page 1 to 10
       // if you want to get text from full pdf file use this code
       // pdfStripper.setEndPage(pdDoc.getNumberOfPages());

       Text = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
       return Text;
   }

    public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }
}
```

The Error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.RandomAccessFile cannot be cast to org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessRead
>       at aechaec.PDFManager.ToText(PDFManager.java:43)
>       at aechaec.AechAEC.main(AechAEC.java:25)
>   Java Result: 1

is it caused by security privileges ? because I'm using Netbeans on mac?

Comment: I was wondering if you are using Maven?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are many outdated examples around, they may or may not work. Please replace this code

```
file = new File(filePath);
parser = new PDFParser(new RandomAccessFile(file,"r"));
parser.parse();
cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
```

which this code:

```
pdDoc = PDDocument.load(new File(filePath));
pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
```

and update to the release version of 2.0.

Comment: well it's been a while, but PDFParser constructor want an RandomAccessRead instance, instead of RandomAccessFile.. How to get it? Any idea much appreciated.

Comment: Either do what is in the answer, or if you really want to use the outdated `PDFParser` constructor, then use the `RandomAccessFile` or `RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream` constructors.